# Biber can't call method "get_field" on an undefined value

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber, perl

Is this a bug, has the behaviour changed (i.e. it is a new 'feature') or is the end user simply an idiot?

When I try to run Biber on code which compiled just fine until quite recently (i.e. prior to a quite recent update of TeX Live), I get the following error:

```
Can't call method "get_field" on an undefined value at /tmp/par-636672656573/cache-c198dfb38941e814f5331b149bc84facd9e9c2e6/inc/lib/Biber.pm line 2247.
```

MWEB:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@bookinbook{entry1,
  ids           =   {entry3},
  title         =   {Original Title},
  crossref      =   {entry2},
  origdate      =   1098}
@bookinbook{entry4,
  title         =   {Another Original Title},
  crossref      =   {entry2},
  origdate      =   1076}
@inbook{entry2,
  author        =   {Author, A. N.},
  title         =   {Collected Works},
  publisher     =   {Old Books 'n Stuff},
  location      =   cam,
  date          =   {2003}}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{places.bib}
@string{cam     =   {Cambridge}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{places,\jobname}
\begin{document}
\textcite{entry1}
\begin{refsection}
  \textcite{entry3,entry4,entry2}
  \printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

Note that testing suggests that the error does not occur if

- the citation of `entry3` is changed to use `entry1`;
- `refsection` is not used;
- nothing is cited outside the `refsection`;
- `@string{...}` is included in `\jobname.bib`;
- only `entry4` is not cited within the `refsection`.

However, I had quite a lot of difficulty coming up with the MWEB so some double-checking by a fresh brain would be appreciated. I may just be extremely confused.

Line 2247 of the `.pm` file Biber complains about is:

```
    my $bee = $be->get_field('entrytype');
```

I am using Biber version 2.2.

Comment: I can confirm the issue, with Biber version 2.2.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. That's the second confirmation. So it looks like a bug to you? This worked until very, very recently. (Which is why I spent ages combing through my *new* code because I 'knew' the earlier stuff worked. Pah.)

Comment: Bug report at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/93.

Comment: Should be fixed in the dev 2.3 version on Sourceforge

Comment: @PLK Excellent! I will see if I can manage to test it ;).

Comment: `biblatex` 3.2 and Biber 2.3 are on CTAN now and should be available in TeX live and MikTeX. In my tests the error did not re-appear. Would you be able to confirm that?

Comment: @moewe I don't get an error with my MWEB, so I assume it is fixed. I can't remember which document I had trouble with. I think a course packet, but I either changed it to workaround the problem or it got fixed quickly enough that I didn't need to. At least, I seem to have been using the default stuff even before updating TeX Live in response to your comment.

Comment: Does that mean we can close this question as "fixed by an update"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue raised has been fixed by an update.

Comment: @moewe Seems reasonable to me ;).